# Font in Gnuplot Postscript Terminal

Tags: gnuplot

I would like gnuplot to use the same font in the postscript-terminal as it does in the wxt-terminal. The Gnuplot help says that wxt uses "Sans" by default. Now, if i set the terminal to

```
gnuplot> set term post enhanced color "Sans" 12
Terminal type set to 'postscript'
Options are 'landscape enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashed dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   "Sans" 12 '
```

then the font looks very different to the one in wxt.
I am using Ubuntu 10.04 lucid.
Which font would you suggest me to use? Any ideas welcome.
I've also tried "cm-super" to get latex-fonts (computer modern) in gnuplot. Actually it worked, but the text overlapped boxes and margins very often!

Greets,
mefiX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the considered plots are part of a LaTeX document, I decided to use the computer modern fonts described earlier.

```
gnuplot> set term post enhanced color fontfile "/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1200.pfb" "SFSS1200"
Terminal type set to 'postscript'
Font file '/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1200.pfb' contains the font 'SFSS1200'. Location:
   /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1200.pfb
Options are 'landscape enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault color colortext \
   dashed dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 butt noclip \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   "SFSS1200" 14 fontfile "/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfss1200.pfb" '
```

As already mentioned, you can install these under ubuntu by calling

```
# apt-get install cm-super
```

on the root command line.

Note that the characters in `SFSS1200` describe font encoding (Latin1, ...), style (Sans-Serif, ...) and desired resolution in dpi.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found out you also need to install `groff` in order to obtain `pfbtops`. Moreover, in Gnuplot 5 your example results in a rotated plot. What worked was `set term postscript eps color fontfile "/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1200.pfb" "SFRM1200,24"`. Note that the 24 at the end is the font size.